# How can i get the plugin name of a grep filepath result?

Tags: regex, sorting, plugins, grep

I have used `grep -rsl "tinymce.plugins" . | sort` to get a longer list of files including references to tinyMCE plugins. Here is a short excerpt of what the results list looks like:

```
./assets/javascripts/old/tiny_mce/plugins/preview/editor_plugin.js
./assets/javascripts/old/tiny_mce/plugins/preview/editor_plugin_src.js
./assets/javascripts/old/tiny_mce/plugins/print/editor_plugin.js
./assets/javascripts/old/tiny_mce/plugins/print/editor_plugin_src.js
```

I now want to find a way to make a list with all the plugin names and put it into a file.

Example:

results.txt:

preview
print

How can i achieve this? Thank you and sorry if my english is clunky.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below grep command,

```
$ command | grep -oP '[^\/]*(?=\/[^\/]*$)' | sort -u
preview
print
```

Comment: Should probably be `sort|uniq` (or simply `sort -u`) to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

this awk one-liner gives you the result in one shot:

```
whatever|awk -F'plugins/' '{sub("/.*","",$2);$0=$2}!a[$0]++'
```

with your four lines, it outputs:

```
preview
print
```